# why am I getting an 'invalid column' error?

Tags: sql, ssms

I am getting an 'invalid column' error concerning 'ordervalue'. Using a HAVING statement instead of WHERE doesn't fix it, and removing the '>10000' filter allows the code to run fine.

What am I missing?

Thank you

```
select
    customers.customerid,
    customers.companyname,
    orderdetails.orderid,
    ordervalue = orderdetails.quantity * OrderDetails.UnitPrice
from
    customers
join
    orders
on
    customers.customerid = orders.customerid
join
    orderdetails
on
    orderdetails.orderid = orders.orderid
where
    orders.orderdate > '20160101' and
    orders.orderdate < '20161231' and
    ordervalue > 10000
order by
    ordervalue desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `WHERE` clause, which is attempting to refer to the alias `ordervalue`.  This is not allowed in standard SQL.  You should just repeat the expression:

```
where
    orders.orderdate > '20160101' and
    orders.orderdate < '20161231' and
    orderdetails.quantity * OrderDetails.UnitPrice > 10000
```